# Using makes or causes

Tags: word-choice, causatives

I understand the meaning of  the words **makes** and **causes**.  However, I'm having a hard time explaining to a student (that I volunteer with) as to why **makes** seems to be a better choice in the following sentences:

1. The medicine **makes** me feel better.
2. The medicine **causes** me to feel better.

The first sentence sounds more natural to me, but I cant explain why.

Can someone help?  Thank you.

Comment: It sounds more natural because it is. It's the way people talk. It would be a more formal or technical usage to say the medicine *causes* someone to feel better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose sometimes I just try to over analyse things.

Answer (score 2):

By itself, "make" is neither positive nor negative:

> I like going to visit my elderly neighbor.  She always **makes** me feel at home.
>
> I hate going to visit my elderly neighbor.  She always **makes** me feel  unwelcome.

Similarly, "cause" is neutral:

> By just stepping on the stage, the Beatles always **caused** the teenage girls in the audience to start screaming.
>
> The drug **causes** an adverse reaction in patients with a history of heart disease.

So why "make" not "cause"?  As Robusto says in the above comment, "make" just sounds less *forceful* and somewhat nicer.

However you could use either, depending on the context

> This drug **makes** me feel better (because I want to feel better)
>
> This drug **causes** me to feel better (even when I don't want to feel better).